# Index of summations

Tags: probability-theory, summation, summation-method

I have two powers of binomials, $(1+x)^A$ and $(1+x)^B$.

By the binomial theorem theorem $(1+x)^A = \sum_{k}^{A}\binom{A}{k}x^k$ (1)

and $(1+x)^B = \sum_{k}^{B}\binom{B}{k}x^k$  (2)

Instead of this notation, for the summation (1) I write $\sum_{n}\binom{A}{n}x^n$

and for the summation (2) I write $\sum_{m}\binom{B}{m}x^m$.

Is the subindex $n$ the same than the index "$k=1$ to $A$" in (1) and the subindex $m$ the same than "$k=1$ to $B$" in (2)?

If I write $\sum_{n,m}\binom{A}{n}\binom{B}{m}x^{n+m}$ is the same than

$\sum_{k}^{A}\binom{A}{k}x^k \cdot  \sum_{k}^{B}\binom{B}{k}x^k$?

If this change of notation is right, is it usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play fast & loose with your summation variables like that. But I find it helpful to keep tighter track of them ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \left( \sum_{i=0}^{A} \binom {A}{i} x^i \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{B} \binom {B}{j} x^j \right) & =&  (1+x)^A (1+x)^B =(1+x)^{A+B} \\ 
 & =& \sum_{k=0}^{A+B} \binom {A+B}{k} x^k. 
\end{eqnarray*}
So now calculating the product above and equating coefficients $x^k$ gives 
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{i+j=k} \binom {A}{i} \binom {B}{j} =  \binom {A+B}{k}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Which is the Vandermonde convolution identity.

Comment: In $\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{i+j=k} \binom {A}{i} \binom {B}{j} =  \binom {A+B}{k}. 
\end{eqnarray*}$ Does the subindex $i$ go from $0$ to $A$ and the subindex $j$  from $0$ to $B$?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{i+j=k} \binom {A}{i} \binom {B}{j} =  \sum_{i=0}^{ \color{red}{\min(A,B)}} \binom {A}{i} \binom {B}{k-i}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that if we extended the index variable further, one or other of the binomial coefficients would be zero, so it would not matter.

Comment: In my notes I have $\sum_{k,l}k\binom{A}{k}\binom{B}{l}x^{x-1+l}$. Can I assume that the subindex $k$ goes from $0$ to $A$ and $l$ from $0$ to $B$?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k,l}\color{blue}{k} \binom{A}{k}\binom{B}{l}x^{\color{red}{?}-1+l}= \sum_{\color{blue}{k=1}}^{A} \sum_{l=0}^{B} k \binom{A}{k}\binom{B}{l}x^{k-1+l}.
\end{eqnarray*}
That's why it is a good idea to write your summation limits clearly. It will save you trouble later.

Comment: Sorry. I meant .In my notes I have $\sum_{k,l}k\binom{A}{k}\binom{B}{l}x^{k-1+l}$. Can I assume that the subindex $k$ goes from $0$ to $A$ and $l$ from $0$ to $B$?

Comment: You can assume the lower limit of $k$ is zero (if you wish) but note that the summand is zero in this case & therefore will give any contribution to the sum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101625/discussion-between-donald-splutterwit-and-ron-jacobs).